# Highlight email?

Tags: email, highlighting

I often find certain portions of email more important than the rest, so is there a way for me to highlight or mark certain sentences for future reference?

Are there any mail clients that support something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Outlook lets you open a message and then edit it. You can then apply any formatting operation to it (including highlighting if the email is in HTML/Rich Text) before closing it.

Open the message into it's own window, then Edit -> Edit Message, and bring up the formatting toolbar.

---

The other option is to just forward the email to yourself, and edit it with highlighting before you send it.

Answer (score 0):

none has the ability (which is a feature long asked for by power email users).

My current setup involves Thunderbird with the XNote add-on, and instead of highlighting, I use the notes to indicate important portions of my emails.

You could try that - it's more versatile too.